# Invalid YAML formatting?

Tags: python, flask, yaml, jinja2

Can someone explain why this YAML is invalid?

```
playing_song_artist: Playing song, {{ song_name }} by {{ artist }}

playing_playlist: {{ action }} playlist {{ playlist_name }}
```

The first line is perfectly fine, but I can't figure out what's wrong with the second one...

```
expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'
  in "<string>", line 3, column 32:
    playing_playlist: {{ action }} playlist {{ playlist_name }}
```

Comment: What are the substituted values of `action`, `artist`, `song_name` and `playlist_name`?

Comment: `Playing` and `Test`, but http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ shows it invalid without even seeing the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `,`, `{` and `}` are [indicator characters](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2772075) in YAML. You can quote the strings that you need to include indicators characters in YAML. Like this,

```
playing_song_artist: "Playing song, {{ song_name }} by {{ artist }}"

playing_playlist: "{{ action }} playlist {{ playlist_name }}"
```

Try this example to see how flow mapping works with `,`, `{` and `}`

```
playing_song_artist : {a and b, hello}
```

Comment: `{}` is not an indicator character. `{` and `}` are. Also note that using `"` around a string might change its scalar value when loaded (e.g. when there would be a backslash in the original string)

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking, the YAML parser is trying to infer the type of the value and because the syntax of the value does not match its inference, the parser is failing.

```
{{ action }} playlist {{ playlist_name }}
```

And because the `{` is the first character, it can’t figure out whether it is supposed to be looking at a string (e.g., for a template expansion) or a `dict`.  Because of the `{`, the YAML parser is expecting a dict but, of course, `{{ action }}` isn’t a valid dict, so the YAML parser fails.  If you want to treat that value as a string, just surround it with double quotes.

```
playing_playlist: "{{ action }} playlist {{ playlist_name }}"
```

Whereas in the first example string:

```
Playing song, {{ song_name }} by {{ artist }}
```

`Playing` is a string, so the YAML parser can infer that the type of the entire value is a string.

Answer (score 1):

The parser is confused by the world "playlist", as it just has parsed a flowstyle mapping and is expected an end-of-line (or possible a comment) but not a scalar.

For both mapping values the parser starts processing the block mapping value after encountering `:`. To parse the mapping value to a [plain style scalar](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788859), as in your first mapping entry, that value can start with a [ns-char](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#ns-char), but not with a [c-indicator](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#c-indicator). The production rule 22, for the latter, gives you a list with which a plain style scalar (i.e. a scalar without quotes) **cannot** begin:

```
[22] c-indicator ::= “-” | “?” | “:” | “,” | “[” | “]” | “{” | “}”
                     | “#” | “&” | “*” | “!” | “|” | “>” | “'” | “"”
                     | “%” | “@” | “`”
```

and if that would be unclear the following line states:

> The “[”, “]”, “{”, “}” and “,” indicators denote structure in flow collections. They are therefore forbidden in some cases, to avoid ambiguity in several constructs. This is handled on a case-by-case basis by the relevant productions.

In this particular case `{` starts a flow mapping, which is fine, but as indicated you cannot have "content" following the closing `}`

Therefore you cannot have a plain scalar, and have either have to put quotes around the scalar, e.g. single ones:

```
laying_playlist: '{{ action }} playlist {{ playlist_name }}'
```

or double ones:

```
laying_playlist: "{{ action }} playlist {{ playlist_name }}"
```

But *putting quotes around a plain scalar might change its value* if there are backslashes resp. single quotes within the string, so it is probably safest to
 make it into a literal block style scalar with its final newline stripped:

```
laying_playlist: |-
     {{ action }} playlist {{ playlist_name }}
```

This confusion is caused by the use of `{{` and `}}` to surround substitutions, it would have been much better to select a character combination that didn't start with a YAML `[c-indicator][3]`, but that is still relatively unique in a text. E.g `<{` and `}>` would not give a problem as `<` can start a plain scalar in YAML.